# How do I reject my own In-App Purchase that is Waiting for Review?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have about 25 In-App Purchase objects (IAPs) that I want to go live with a new update of my app. This is my first update with IAPs.

**What Went Wrong:**

I created 5 IAPs, and then submitted my app with a "developer controlled" release so it didn't go to the store until I had finished creating & submitting the rest of my IAPs, which would take me several days to complete. This seemed like a very logical plan to me (it would save me 4-5 days of calendar time, and the code can handle new IAPs dynamically), and after reading Apple's (VERY UNCLEAR) documentation on IAPs, I thought it would be possible.

Several days after submission, I finished my IAPs, but upon trying to submit them iTunes Connect then informed me that no IAPs will be approved unless they work on the 'current version'. Since my update would not be published without these IAPs, clearly my time-saving plan didn't work. Bummer!

So, I rejected my new update binary, thinking I would just re-submit with all 25 IAPs. No big deal. But after rejecting the binary, the original 5 IAPs were not rejected; they are still stuck in a 'Waiting for Review', and are thus unavailable for me to add to my update in the Version Details page.

**Core Question:**

How can I reject my own IAPs that are in the 'Waiting for Review' state?

If there is no way, it would seem my only option is to wait for my 5 old IAPs to be rejected, because only then would all 25 be available for submission, right..?

So much for saving time. =/

Comment: Submit a request through the iTunes Connect contact form?

Comment: fair suggestion; will update this question with Apple's response

Comment: @Kinderchocolate - Still waiting for response from Apple. Their front-line support could not find my IAPs in their systems, so they have pushed me to some engineering group for further support. Huge delay on my release. Doh. =/

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? I'm having a similar issue, rejected binary and now can't add in my iAP with the re-submission.

Comment: @primulaveris - If you reject and re-submit, the IAPs that were associated will automatically associate. There is no UI to tell you this, but I've done it on multiple releases with different Apps now and it's worked. Of course your mileage may vary. =/